# Word Add-in behavior different in El Capitan vs. Sierra

Tags: webkit, osx-elcapitan, macos-sierra, office-js

My Annotate PRO Add-in behaves just fine across Word Online, Windows, and macOS Sierra.

Office Store [link](https://store.office.com/en-us/app.aspx?assetid=WA104380754&sourcecorrid=3fb659ee-fa63-43c5-9469-17ee0b435c8a&searchapppos=0&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&appredirect=false) if you want to try it.

Users on 10.11.6 have reported that when opening the Annotate taskpane they get the message that, essentially, says they aren't on Word 2016 with WordAPI 1.1.

Same message you get if you browse directly to the [taskpane html](https://www.11trees.com/annotate/word/prod/annotateHome.html).

I have validated this behavior on a mac running 10.11.6 and using Microsoft Word 2016 (15.32).

The gold standard for me, when developing and learning the new Microsoft approach, is Word Online. If it works there then it should work...and Microsoft approved my Extension.

So I'm concerned that there is an issue with 10.11.6 that doesn't affect Sierra users. Perhaps something in webkit? My add-in works just fine in Word Online using Safari on 10.11.6.

A related issue/question concerns whether the Add-in appears as a tab in Word.

Annotate appears in Word 2016 Sierra as a tab, like Insert, Review etc.

It does not appear in Word 2016 (with all updates) running on 10.11.6.

Not sure if being part of the "Office Insider Slow" updates plan affects this...but I thought it material and worth mentioning. My Sierra development machine is part of the "Office Insider Slow" updates but the 10.11.6 machine is not.

I will post the manifest XML as a separate question and add the link as a comment.

Any Microsoft or other expert help deeply appreciated. This is a major blocker for me - I can't go to the marketplace with "only works on Sierra with Office Insider Slow" requirements.

Comment: OK, so just to be sure:  we are only talking about the Mac, correct?  Let me pass it on to the team.

Comment: Yes - sorry if not clear. Mac 10.11.6. I haven't been able to test on anything lower than that.

Here's the link to the XML/manifest question - in case things are related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43007225/why-does-a-word-2016-add-in-office-js-ribbon-tab-not-show-for-some-mac-users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced my problem to the use of 'const' while in 'use strict'...

I was using a code snippet from Firebase/Google (for authentication across all my apps/websites) that declared a variable using “const”.

In “use strict” this is not allowed in older versions of WebKit. It’s been fixed, which is why Sierra was okay (I guess).

See [https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=161464][1].

But it threw an error on 10.11.6 and (I guess) earlier.

**Here is the crucial bit of info**: how to turn on debugging for WebKit (when used as an embedded browser):

Run the following command using terminal on your Mac:

```
defaults write com.Microsoft.OsfWebHost WebKitDeveloperExtras -bool true
```

After you've run this in Terminal you can right-click on the taskpane and debug...

This isn't an official/supported approach by Apple...but it's working now. Miraculous.

Comment: Hello, turning on the WebKit inspector on Word for Mac 16.11 does not seem to work anymore. Do you perhaps have any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: Yeah - I noticed this. Advice from Microsoft is to use Word Onlline. If you use Safari you will be using the same webkit engine (my assumption and has worked so far). Then you can open console in Safari to troubleshoot...

Comment: How can i enable webkit inspector on word for mac 16.10 with high sierra? I am able to see inspector in lower version of Mac OS EI Capitan and word version 15.X.. ? Could you please help me here, it is very difficult to trace issue on latest mac OS and word version?