# Why does a Word 2016 Add-in (office.js) Ribbon Tab not show for some Mac users?

Tags: xml, macos, ms-word, osx-elcapitan, office-js

The following manifest was approved by Microsoft and is in the Office Store as an add-in for Word 2016 called "Annotate PRO."

The manifest should create a new ribbon named 'Annotate.' It does this correctly in Windows, Word Online (Windows and Mac, Chrome and Safari), and on some Macs. On most Macs (especially El Capitan) it does not create a Ribbon although the Add-in does work. You just have to choose it from 'My Add-ins' every time you open a document.

It does not appear on many Macs. Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides"
xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">

<Id>2c77d848-f893-4938-ad5f-5ea03d3608dc</Id>
<Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
<ProviderName>11trees</ProviderName>
<DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
<!-- <DisplayName DefaultValue="Annotate PRO" /> -->
<DisplayName DefaultValue="Annotate PRO LOCAL" />
<Description DefaultValue="Access a library of pre-written comments that you can edit and extend to suit your needs. Add detailed feedback with one click!" />
<IconUrl DefaultValue="https://www.11trees.com/images/annotate/Annotate-32x32-circle.png" />
<SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.11trees.com/live/support/" />

 <!--Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog -->

<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://trees-3aac6.firebaseio.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://www.firebaseapp.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://www.googleapis.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://www.facebook.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>

<Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document"/>
</Hosts>

<Requirements>
   <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
     <Set Name="WordApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
   </Sets>
 </Requirements>

<!-- Comment in/our local vs. production here and bottom of file... -->

<DefaultSettings>
  <!-- Local Windows -->
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://localhost/AnnotateforWord_dev/AnnotateCode/annotateHome.html" />
  <!-- Local macOS -->
  <!-- <SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://localhost/AnnotateX/AnnoWord/annotateHome.html" /> -->
  <!-- Staging -->
  <!-- <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.11trees.com/annotate/word/beta/AnnotateCode/annotateHome.html" /> -->
  <!-- Production -->
    <!-- <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://www.11trees.com/annotate/word/prod/annotateHome.html" /> -->

</DefaultSettings>

<Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <!--BeginAddinCommandsMode integration-->
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <!--Each host can have a different set of commands. Cool huh!? -->
      <!-- Workbook=Excel Document=Word Presentation=PowerPoint -->
      <!-- Make sure the hosts you override match the hosts declared in the top section of the manifest -->
      <Host xsi:type="Document">
        <!-- Form factor. Currenly only DesktopFormFactor is supported. We will add TabletFormFactor and PhoneFormFactor in the future-->
        <DesktopFormFactor>

           <!--GetStarted information used on the callout that appears when installing the add-in.
            Ensure you have build 16.0.6769 or above for GetStarted section to work-->
          <GetStarted>
                        <!--Title of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a ShortString resource -->
                        <Title resid="11trees.GetStarted.Title"/>

                        <!--Description of the Getting Started callout. resid points to a LongString resource -->
                        <Description resid="11trees.GetStarted.Description"/>

                        <!--Not used right now but you need to provide a valid resource. We will add code in the future to consume this URL.
                            resid points to a Url resource -->
                        <LearnMoreUrl resid="11trees.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
                    </GetStarted>

            <!--Function file is an html page that includes the javascript where functions for ExecuteAction will be called.
            Think of the FunctionFile as the "code behind" ExecuteFunction-->
          <FunctionFile resid="11trees.FunctionFile.Url" />

          <!--PrimaryCommandSurface==Main Office Ribbon-->
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <!--Use OfficeTab to extend an existing Tab. Use CustomTab to create a new tab -->
            <!-- Documentation includes all the IDs currently tested to work -->
            <CustomTab id="11trees.Tab1">
                      <!--Group. Ensure you provide a unique id. Recommendation for any IDs is to namespace using your company name-->
              <Group id="11trees.Tab1.Group1">
                 <!--Label for your group. resid must point to a ShortString resource -->
                <Label resid="11trees.Tab1.GroupLabel" />
                <Icon>
                <!-- Sample Todo: Each size needs its own icon resource or it will look distorted when resized -->
                <!--Icons. Required sizes 16,31,80, optional 20, 24, 40, 48, 64. Strongly recommended to provide all sizes for great UX -->
                <!--Use PNG icons and remember that all URLs on the resources section must use HTTPS -->
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                </Icon>

              <!-- The custom button (execute function) was here -->

                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="11trees.TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>Button2Id1</TaskpaneId>
                     <!--Provide a url resource id for the location that will be displayed on the task pane -->
                    <SourceLocation resid="11trees.Taskpane1.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
            <!-- Menu example -->
            <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="11trees.Menu">
              <Label resid="11trees.Dropdown.Label" />
              <Supertip>
                <Title resid="11trees.Dropdown.Label" />
                <Description resid="11trees.Dropdown.Tooltip" />
              </Supertip>
              <Icon>
                <bt:Image size="16" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                <bt:Image size="32" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                <bt:Image size="80" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
              </Icon>
              <Items>
                <!-- Home and account page -->
                <Item id="11trees.Menu.Item1">
                  <Label resid="11trees.Item1.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="11trees.Item1.Label" />
                    <Description resid="11trees.Item1.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                  </Icon>
                  <!-- Insert Comments Page -->
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>MyTaskPaneID1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="11trees.Taskpane2.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Item>
                <Item id="11trees.Menu.Item2">
                  <Label resid="11trees.Item2.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="11trees.Item2.Label" />
                    <Description resid="11trees.Item2.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>MyTaskPaneID2</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="11trees.Taskpane3.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Item>

              </Items>
            </Control>

              </Group>

              <!-- Label of your tab -->
              <!-- If validating with XSD it needs to be at the end, we might change this before release -->
              <Label resid="11trees.Tab1.TabLabel" />
            </CustomTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Icon" DefaultValue="https://www.11trees.com/images/annotate/Annotate-128x128-circle.png" />
        <bt:Image id="11trees.FunctionButton.Icon" DefaultValue="https://www.11trees.com/images/annotate/Annotate-128x128-circle.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>

<!-- Local macOS -->
        <bt:Url id="11trees.FunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="http://localhost/AnnotateX/AnnoWord/functionFile.html" />
        <bt:Url id="11trees.Taskpane1.Url" DefaultValue="http://localhost/AnnotateX/AnnoWord/AnnotateCode/annotateHome.html" />
        <bt:Url id="11trees.Taskpane2.Url" DefaultValue="http://localhost/AnnotateX/AnnoWord/AnnotateCode/insertComment.html" />
        <bt:Url id="11trees.Taskpane3.Url" DefaultValue="http://localhost/AnnotateX/AnnoWord/AnnotateCode/enterComment.html" />



<!-- Local Windows -->
        <!-- <bt:Url id="11trees.FunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="http://localhost/AnnotateforWord_dev/AnnotateCode/functionFile.html" /> -->
        <!-- <bt:Url id="11trees.Taskpane1.Url" DefaultValue="http://localhost/AnnotateforWord_dev/AnnotateCode/annotateHome.html" /> -->
        <!-- <bt:Url id="11trees.Taskpane2.Url" DefaultValue="http://localhost/AnnotateforWord_dev/AnnotateCode/insertComment.html" /> -->
        <!-- <bt:Url id="11trees.Taskpane3.Url" DefaultValue="http://localhost/AnnotateforWord_dev/AnnotateCode/enterComment.html" /> -->

<!-- Staging -->

        <!-- <bt:Url id="11trees.FunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="http://localhost/AnnotateforWord_dev/AnnotateCode/functionFile.html" />
        <bt:Url id="11trees.Taskpane1.Url" DefaultValue="https://www.11trees.com/annotate/word/beta/AnnotateCode/annotateHome.html" />
        <bt:Url id="11trees.Taskpane2.Url" DefaultValue="https://www.11trees.com/annotate/word/beta/AnnotateCode/insertComment.html" />
        <bt:Url id="11trees.Taskpane3.Url" DefaultValue="https://www.11trees.com/annotate/word/beta/AnnotateCode/enterComment.html" /> -->

<!-- Production -->
        <!-- <bt:Url id="11trees.FunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="https://www.11trees.com/annotate/word/prod/functionFile.html" />
        <bt:Url id="11trees.Taskpane1.Url" DefaultValue="https://www.11trees.com/annotate/word/prod/annotateHome.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="11trees.Taskpane2.Url" DefaultValue="https://www.11trees.com/annotate/word/prod/insertComment.html" />
        <bt:Url id="11trees.Taskpane3.Url" DefaultValue="https://www.11trees.com/annotate/word/prod/enterComment.html" /> -->

         <!--LearnMore URL currently not used -->
        <bt:Url id="11trees.GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://11trees.com/live/support/">
        </bt:Url>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="11trees.FunctionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Execute Function" />
        <bt:String id="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Annotate Home" />
        <bt:String id="11trees.Dropdown.Label" DefaultValue="Actions" />
        <bt:String id="11trees.Item1.Label" DefaultValue="Insert Comments" />
        <bt:String id="11trees.Item2.Label" DefaultValue="Edit Comment Library" />
        <bt:String id="11trees.Tab1.GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Annotate Basics" />
         <bt:String id="11trees.Tab1.TabLabel" DefaultValue="Annotate" />
         <bt:String id="11trees.GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Annotate for Word add-in was succesfully loaded">
          <bt:Override Locale="ja-jp" Value="JA-JP Get Started Title" />
        </bt:String>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="11trees.FunctionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Execute Function" />
        <bt:String id="11trees.TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="11trees.Dropdown.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show Options on this Menu" />
        <bt:String id="11trees.Item1.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Insert Comments" />
        <bt:String id="11trees.Item2.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Edit Your Library" />
          <bt:String id="11trees.GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue="Get going by clicking the Annotate tab on the Ribbon">
          <bt:Override Locale="ja-jp" Value="JA-JP Get Started Title" />
        </bt:String>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>

</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add-In Commands are still in preview for Mac so if it's an old build of the Mac apps they wouldn't be supported
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-Commands-Samples/blob/master/Tools/MacDevPreview.md

Comment: Thank you!. I'm only on 'Office Insider Slow,' but maybe they've released "Add-in Commands" to that level of test in advance of wider release. I'll update my installation/use documentation to reflect this.

Comment: Commands for Mac are currently available on Insiders Fast and Insiders Slow. Will rollout beyond insiders within the next month

Comment: I'm seeing same issue with Windows users - mostly at universities with (probably) slow update processes. Is the status of features/capabilities summarized anywhere (by version of Office, perhaps)?